# Block visits to a specific url with fail2ban

Tags: security, nginx

On one of my sites, bots continually vist this url:

`comment/reply/es/user/password?name=changename`

The url doesn't exist, but there are a lot of incoming IP addresses, and I don't want to block them one at a time. A few days ago I installed `fail2ban` and tried to see how to block several addresses trying to get `ssh` access.

Is there any rule I can use to block bot searching for an arbitrary url?

I tried this:

```
    [apache-badbots]

enabled  = true
port    = http,http
filter   = apache-badbots
logpath  = /var/log/nginx*/*access.log
bantime  = 172800
maxretry = 1
```

But I think this doesn't work. For instance, you can see I'm using nginx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use your access log as base for fail2ban.

If you want to filter requests to a (not existing) URL you have to use your error log (this is the place where all erroneous requests go).

Use a custom filter (ex. *apache-badbots.conf*) for fail2ban (mostly under */etc/fail2ban/filter.d/*) with a matching pattern.

After that you can enable your new filter in your *jail.conf*

Comment: Thanks for the answer, already I change to error log. Im not shure how to create a pattern. Im using a jail.local to enabled sections.